# Postgres - Escaping a Question Mark (?) in a column name

Tags: postgresql, escaping

One of the columns in a Postgres DB I inherited has a question mark in the name.

When I try to select it, it throws an error

```
> select confirmed? from user_purchases;

ERROR:  column "confirmed" does not exist
LINE 1: select confirmed? from user_purchases;
               ^
HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the column "user_purchases.confirmed?".
```

I've also tried selecting it with backticks (`confirmed?`) and quotes ("confirmed?") but the same error is raised.

How do I select this field?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use double quote:

```
 select "confirmed?" from user_purchases;
```

**[DEMO](http://rextester.com/ILM31588)**

Comment: Thanks! So I had tried this and it didn't work, but I just realized that I was using a table alias, which I hadn't made clear in the original question. So for anyone else in the same situation using table aliases, it's `select up."confirmed?" from user_purchases up`.